# How to query by ising data and time with using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch  record based on my where condition.

This is my query.

```
select * from student where createdDate = '04/18/2013 03:24:49';
```

But I am not getting any record...

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? MSQL?

Comment: oracle data base and sql developer

Comment: Data type for createdDate column? Are you sure there are any rows from that specific second to return?

Comment: i have one record with this '04/18/2013 03:24:49'

Comment: @lara123 - how are you querying and displaying to see that value? What is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT? I suspect it has HH instead of HH24 (and no AM/PM indicator), and that record is 3PM. You shouldn't rely on implicit conversion - use `to_date` or a timestamp literal as the answers show.

Comment: I see you received a good answer.  But for future questions, try listing more information like your database table schema, and perhaps a sample record. Additionally, searching for an exact timestamp like '04/18/2013 03:24:49' seems like you are heading in a direction that will contain many more headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your createdDate column is of type date, you should use [to_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function:

```
select * from student where createdDate = to_date('mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss', '04/18/2013 03:24:49');
```

Comment: The mask should have mm/dd rather than dd/mm - since 18 isn't a valid month number.

Answer (score 2):

This is no valid datetime literal you are using. Use this instead:

```
select * from student where createdDate = timestamp'2013-04-18 03:24:49';
```

Comment: @lara123 - are you sure you really have a record created at 3 a.m.? !Maybe you need the tim epart to be 15:24:09?